# Best practice to divide Resource files in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, resx

I got my MVC site setup and ready to use multi languages thanks to this article: http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/

What is the best practice to divide my resource files? Should I use one large resource file per language or should I have a resource file per page I use?

Any comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer is "it depends". If total number of texts is small, then you probably want just 1 resx file per language. If it gets too messy / too large, split them into logical units.

In the past I have used 1 set of files for general texts (Submit, OK, Cancel, Login, Search, Error) and 1 set of files for domain-specific texts (Customer, Product, Basket, Sold out, Payment). The first set of files is then a possible reuse candidate for other projects.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was already thinking about indeed seperating the general texts with the more specific. Looks like I was thinking in the right direction then.

Comment: I couldn't resist to give some arguments for the opposite solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: based on my own experience;*

**Short story: use only one file, it has less overhead when dealing with non-visual-studio, non-xml-translators**

I used to split the forms, pages, etc. in multiple files.

At first this seems like a good way to give a bit of structure to these files: one page, one file.

The benefit is that you don't have a large file, containing all kind of keys. You have short files and it's relatively easy to spot the unused keys.

*But...*

Even in larger projects, for me this is hard to manage. Let me explain;

Typically I don't do all the translations myself. Of course I can handle my native language and with a spell checker, my English isn't terrible. But when it comes to (for me) foreign languages, usually **an other person will do the translations** for me. **This person does not always has visual studio experience and doesn't know how to handle any kind of XML format** (as the `resx` files are).

When a project evolves, keys will come and go. So, syncing all the keys during the projects development does not has the highest priority; the missing keys will default to the default language. To make things worse, during beta releases, or upgrades, you will find that some effort will be taken to do some initial translations which will change over time or will become obsolete.

So, like always: **change will come**.

Now, to manage these changes, if I use separate files, I'll need to do the following to get the translations. Note; the translator doesn't have visual studio or xml experience.

**for each file**

- delete all keys from the target language (to remove obsolete keys which weren't maintained)
- copy the keys to excel
- copy the common translation to the excel file
- structure this in a way so you can past it back in the target resx files
- send the file to the translator and get some coffee while awaiting the response
- copy the translation into each resx file

Then you're done.

So, getting tired of all the copy/pasting, I recently did the following:

Use a prefix to target the page; e.g.: `HOME_Title` and put all in one file.

The process of translation is now reduced to this:

**for one (1) file**

- delete all keys of the foreign language file to get rid of obsolete keys.
- copy the keys and common translation to excel (one action)
- send the file to the translator and try some tea for a change while awaiting the response
- copy the translation, with a single action into your huge `resx` file.

For me this works better, since, I don't care about how big the file is and I actually find the translation process more structured. It might take longer for the translator because he/she has more keys to process when having minor changes. But you can handle this per prefix if you would like. And besides, sometimes more context will result in a better translation. Usually the translator has some relation with the product.

So, for me, I would put it all in one file.